# Where to perform calculations on data: in an object or in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I have a PHP application using a MySQL back-end. This is an internal application with only a hundred or so users--we're not getting thousands of requests per second or anything like that.

Currently in our database, I have created what I call "master" views. These views join all lookup tables and perform any row-based calculations. For example, in a table we'll store the `member_id` which references the `members` table. In the view, I will pull over all of the columns from the `members` table. And I do this for all lookup tables. For row-based calculations, these are usually simple calculations like the difference in days between two dates. I have these master views because it makes writing queries (especially for reporting) really easy since all of my joins are already made and any simple calculations have already been made.

My question is--is this the best way to do this? For example, instead of performing all of these calculations within the view, I would move these calculations to my class. So, in my example above, instead of having a column in the view for calculating the difference between two dates (`flock_age`), I would simply write a method in my class to perform this calculation:

```
<?php
class FlockEx extends Flock
{
    public function getFlockAge()
    {
        $date1 = new \DateTime($this->getDatePlaced());
        $date2 = new \DateTime($this->getDatePickedUp());

        $difference = $date1->diff($date2);

        return $difference->days;
    }
}
```

And instead of joining all of these lookup tables, I would simply create new instances of those classes instead:

```
<?php
$flockdb = new FlockDB();
$flock = $flockdb->getFlockById(4);

$memberdb = new MemberDB();
$member = $memberdb->getMemberById($flock->getMemberId());
...
```

Is there a "best" way to do this? Or is the best way simply what works?

Comment: IMHO....I would do everything in the database that I could possibly do as long as it flexed the database's muscles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database should be used to leverage *joins* and *aggregation*. This is where it excels. Computations that *influence joins* or *require joins/aggregates as an artifact* of the computation should usually done in the database itself.

For low-latency/load/cardinality operations, or when the same base dataset cardinality/size is similar, then it often Just Doesn't Matter.

In this case the date-diff (math between two fields in the same record) is fine to do on the client; but it might not be if a join was dependent upon it.

Answer (score 0):

I do as much reporting as possible in the database. I'm a huge OOP proponent, but churning through hundreds or thousands of DB calls and object creation just to get the same number that a single SUM() sql call would provide is just silly.

Also: your question is likely going to be closed because you're asking for opinions. Don't take it personally.

Comment: I knew it was opinion-based, but I didn't know any other way to go about finding the answer to this. Thanks for your input though.

Answer (score 0):

Always do database calculations at DB end itself. It will give you huge performance boost as well.

Read about some DB concepts like `PROCEDURE` & `FUNCTION`